# App new version to the play store, it downloads but not install with error of signature mismatch

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have updated my app new version to the play store and it downloaded as update to existing users but not install with error of signature mismatch. I am using the same signing keystore as of last update. The previous play store update was uploaded as apk and now I updated it as bundle file.

I have checked the keystore comparison and it matches to existing google signing key but still all existing users are not able install the update. I really appreciate if anyone guide me to right direction as i am not able to found any solution to this. I don't want to loose my user base from existing app.

[Playstore Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdiki.png)

Comment: You should get more details. You use Google signing but you have also the same signing keys locally? Or are you talking about the upload signing keys?

Comment: Robert, I am using the same signing keystore as of previous playstore update. App successfully uploaded and live as update on playstore but the existing user on playstore download then not install with error as of screenshot mentioned in my above details.

Comment: So you just have switched to Google Signing, have you uploaded the old signing key to Google, because without it Google won't be able to sign the APK files properly it builds from your bundle file.

Comment: It is build with same google signing If it is not build with old then how it is uploaded and live on playstore with showing update button on playstore to existing install users?

Comment: If you use Google Signing, then the signature is just for uploading. Google repackages the app into multiple APKs and then signed them. Therefore you need to upload your old signature key, otherwise Google has to create a new one (which seem to have happened and caused that you can not install the update).  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en

Comment: I have the old Keystore jks file. How i can get the old signature key? Is there any way on google play console to get that old signature key? Is it possible auto generated by google? I am not aware of that file. Kindly guide me more on this old signature file to get.